# Adding App to Azure AD

Tags: azure, active-directory

Can someone please tell me how to secure my rest api using Azure AD ? I tried registering the APP to Azure AD but it working.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/08/04/use-a-microsoft-account-to-create-web-apps-protected-by-azure-ad-with-vs2013-update-3.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yahiya, you can indeed use Azure AD to secure your web APIs using OAuth 2.0.
Please follow our documentation (like are below) . The basic steps are: signup for an Azure subscription. In Azure AD register a new application (choose the 'web app being developed by your organization' option). Follow our sample apps to code token handling and authorization. Then register a natibe client app or a client web app. Scroll down to the permissions to other apps section for the client app and select your WebAPI permission. Then, users can sign in to the client app (native client or client web app) and the client app will be able to access your web API on their behalf.

• registering apps in Azure AD: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn151122.aspx
• overview of WebAPI authentication scenarios and links to code samples: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn499820.aspx

Hope this helps.